# REST API, oAuth2, spring security and roles

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

In my application I have implemented `oauth2` AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer. Each user in my system has a set of his Roles(Permissions).

I'd like to protect my Spring MVC REST endpoints with oauth2 and security based on User roles.

Is it possible to use oAuth2 authentication/authorization with different Roles(Permissions) that was defined in UserDetails.getAuthorities() method?

My configs:

```
private final static class DBUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DBUserDetails(User user) {
        super(user);
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return getName();
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
            .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/profile/*").hasRole("PERMISSION_ADMIN")                      
                .and().csrf()
                .disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
    }

}  



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1.0/profile")
public class ProfileController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('PERMISSION_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping("/currentUser")
    public User currentUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        return user;
    }

}
```

I'd like to secure `/profile/*` path with user who has `PERMISSION_ADMIN`. But right now anyone with accessToken can get access to this endpoint. Where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use [OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.html) in your *ResourceServerConfiguration* For me it works like this:

```
http
.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/api")
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/oauth/api").access("#oauth2.hasRole('ADMIN')")...
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it in a near few hours! Is any chance to work at same way  from annotations over the methods ?

Comment: @alexanoid to be honest I didn't try. Good point to investigate

Comment: This does not work. There is no method #oauth2.hasRole. The correct method is just hasRole: .antMatchers("/oauth/api").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")